# What is the best approach to collect/define lastvisited information in Grails/spring security?

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-security, grails-domain-class

What is the best practice or approach to get lastvisited information for an user in Grails? For user login, I am using spring security and I want to show few junks of information based on lastvisited date. So far I don't have any property in user domain. Would you please let me know different and possible approaches that i can easily collect aforementioned information within Grails application. Another related query is, how can i combat with aforementioned problem when a user closes a window or tab in browser without pressing logout link/button?

Answer (score 0):

We ended up pretty messy - will be happy to know a better way. We're saving visit info of:

- login - in an action that `spring-security-redirect` points to;
- login by "remember me" - in [`ApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(appEvent)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener.html#onApplicationEvent%28org.springframework.context.ApplicationEvent%29) (we made a service an `ApplicationListener`):

  ```
  if (appEvent instanceof AuthenticationSuccessEvent) {
      if (appEvent.source instanceof RememberMeAuthenticationToken) {
      }
  }
  ```

  Maybe this is the place to collect all the login events.
- logout - in our own `logout` action that redirects to `j_spring_security_logout`.
- we don't log session timeouts.